# AngularJS filter returns HTML incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filter, sanitize

I have a filter that returns HTML, but Angular does not display it correctly.  I have angular-sanitize.min.js included and have tried ng-bind-html with $sce in various places.  I know I'm close, but after wrestling for a couple days on this, I thought I'd ask for some expert insight.  I'm pretty new to Angular and javascript in general.  Thanks for your help.

proof that I have sanitize

```
<script src="lib/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
```

app.js -- sanitize included and filter I'm using

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'clownfishControllers',
  'ngSanitize'
]);

myApp.filter('fmtIt', function () {
  return function (name) {
    var parts = name.split(' "');
    if (parts.length == 2) {
      return "<i>".concat(parts[0], "</i>", ' "', parts[1]);
    } else {
      return "<i>".concat(parts[0], "</i>");
    }
  }
});
```

list.html -- two examples of what I have in the html file

```
<h2 ng-bind-html="item.name | fmtIt"></h2> --strips off html in output
<h2>{{item.name | fmtIt }}</h2>  --shows html tags in output
```

controllers.js -- one of the controllers that I tried injecting $sce into.

```
clownfishControllers.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'Parents', '$sce', function($scope, $http, Parents, $sce) {
  $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.clownfish = data;
    $scope.clownfishOrder = 'name';
    $scope.parents = Parents;
    console.log($scope);

  });
}]);
```

app.js -- two most recent other attempts, I tried this one as an additional filter to stack on fmtIt filter

```
myApp.filter('trustAsHTML', ['$sce', function($sce){
  return function(text) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
  };
}]);
```

-- tried this one initially to get $sce in

```
myApp.filter('fmtIt', function ($sce) {
  return function (name) {
    var parts = name.split(' "');
    if (parts.length == 2) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml("<i>".concat(parts[0], "</i>", ' "', parts[1]));
    } else {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml("<i>".concat(parts[0], "</i>"));
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very hard to tell where your issue is from what you posted, but perhaps a working demo will allow you to compare your implementation and determine what's wrong.

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('NamesCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.names = [
    {first: 'Jennifer Ann', last: 'Meade'},
    {first: 'Colin', last: 'Davis'},
    {first: 'Karen Walker', last: 'Johnson'}
  ];
});

app.filter('fmtIt', function () {
  return function (name) {
    var parts = name.split(' ');
    if (parts.length == 2) {
      return "<i>".concat(parts[0], "</i>", ' ', parts[1]);
    } else {
      return "<i>".concat(parts[0], "</i>");
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.17/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.17/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="NamesCtrl">
  <h1 ng-repeat="name in names"><span ng-bind-html="name.first | fmtIt"></span> {{name.last}}</h1>
</div>
```

The one difference between this demo and your first implementation in the example code you posted, is that I'm splitting on a space not a `"`, but changing that in my demo and corresponding data, doesn't seem to have any impact.

Note that angular.js must be loaded before angular-sanitize.js in your script tags.  Although, if you are properly injecting ngSanitize in your module as you have shown, you'd be getting an injection error.

Comment: The reason I split on the " is because the format of the name has the " in it.  i.e.  Amphiprion ocellaris "Frostbite".  In this example, what I'm trying to accomplish is italicizing Amphpiprion occellaris while leaving "Frostbite" normal.  test.nolapete.com is my work in progress where this applies.  clowncalc.nolapete.com is the current working version.

Comment: I have angular.min.js first

Comment: It seems that I have something else underlying that is preventing the html from displaying.  Going to break it apart and put it back together until I find the issue.  Your example proved to me that it's not my filter that is the problem.

Comment: outsmarted by someone else's CSS font: inherit;  I turned off the CSS and it worked fine.  Started tracking down the culprit and found that.  Good to remember that the answer to what is broken isn't always where it first appears to be.

Comment: Awesome.  Best of luck.  Not sure I deserved the credit for answering the question, but I will update my answer with what worked for you.

Comment: Yes, credit well-deserved.  You confirmed for me that my code was working correctly and your working demo helped me discover that I needed to search elsewhere in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this combination? It works for me.

```
<div ng-bind-html="htmlText | trustAsHTML"></div>
```

You don't need to add double curly braces to `ng-bind-html`'s value.

[ng-bind-html documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Comment: I had already tried that thanks.  I wasn't using the curly braces when I did.  Something else is preventing it from working.  jme11's example proved that.